# aspx dropdownList does not maintain selected value

Tags: asp.net, postback

Inherited code with a dropdownlist which is used to populate some GridViews. When a selection is made in the dropdownlist, the selection does not keep and it jumps back up to the first record. A requently mentioned fix is to add  the !Page.IsPostBack in the Page_Load event, however in doing so does not resolve the issue.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="FullAddress" 
    DataValueField="UniqueRecordID" Width="445px" Height="20px" 
    style="margin-left: 0px" TabIndex="8" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="resetGridsAndLabel">
</asp:DropDownList>

 public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList2.DataSource = sqlDataSource2;
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the data source for the DDL anywhere else on the page?